Large language model (TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GPTQ)
Can someone please list the steps to set up the llama model locally, this model will run without internet on the VM machine.
I am using the below model.
TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GPTQ.
I tried the text generation method but I don't know how to connect it in Python code without the internet.

To run the TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GPTQ model locally in VM

You need a gpu with minimum 8GB configuration. I have used paperspace RTX 4000 for this purpose.
Check the version of CUDA installed on the machine. eg.11.7
Install the torch corresponding to the CUDA version from here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
Install AutoGPTQ from source.
Run code from here https://gist.github.com/rajendrac3/a6feb71c94aff71a71ed7ee97ba94b8d

